# How to make radio buttons required with my css example?js

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

i have some radio buttons which are used for a questionaire, the user can click next ( over 9 pages ) and get a result out of his answers.
I want to achieve it with js and css ( i need the back button working, a normal require would stop the function of my button ).

```js
var invalidClassName = 'invalid'
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input, select, radio')
inputs.forEach(function (input) {
  // Add a css class on submit when the input is invalid.
  input.addEventListener('invalid', function () {
    input.classList.add(invalidClassName)
  })

  // Remove the class when the input becomes valid.
  // 'input' will fire each time the user types
  input.addEventListener('input', function () {
    if (input.validity.valid) {
      input.classList.remove(invalidClassName)
    }
  })
})
```

This is my php function where the table is generated:

```
while ($question = mysqli_fetch_array($quest_query)) {
        $i++;

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th>'.$i.'</th>';
        echo '<th>'.$question['question'].'</th>';
        echo '<th class="text-center"><input type="radio" name="'.$question['dimension'].'_question_'.$question['id'].'" value="0" required '.questionIsSet($question['dimension'].'_question_'.$question['id'],0).'></th>';
        echo '<th class="text-center"><input type="radio" name="'.$question['dimension'].'_question_'.$question['id'].'" value="2.5" '.questionIsSet($question['dimension'].'_question_'.$question['id'],2.5).'></th>';
        echo '<th class="text-center"><input type="radio" name="'.$question['dimension'].'_question_'.$question['id'].'" value="5" '.questionIsSet($question['dimension'].'_question_'.$question['id'],5).'></th>';
        echo '<th class="text-center"><input type="radio" name="'.$question['dimension'].'_question_'.$question['id'].'" value="7.5" '.questionIsSet($question['dimension'].'_question_'.$question['id'],7.5).'></th>';
        echo '<th class="text-center"><input type="radio" name="'.$question['dimension'].'_question_'.$question['id'].'" value="10" '.questionIsSet($question['dimension'].'_question_'.$question['id'],10).'></th>';
        echo '</tr>';
        $dimensions = $question['dimension'];

    }
```

and the css is really simple:

```
input.invalid {
border-color: red;
}
```

do someone have an idea what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Why don't you rely on the html5 validation and CSS `:invalid`?

Comment: what do you mean by that? Can you help me to understand your question probably. Maybe i am missing something

Answer (score 0):

This link will help you understand
[MDN :invalid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid)

```
input:invalid {
   border-color: red;
}
```